# How to remove onchange listener

Tags: jquery, asp.net, google-chrome-extension

It is a ASP.net web page with this element:

```
<input name="cthicleNo" type="text" value="MP28TA8649" maxlength="20" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'cthicleNo\',\'\')', 0)" onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" id="VehicleNo" class="textString">
```

All I want is to change the vehicle number by typing and it should not invoke event listeners.

If I copy a new vehicle number using `$("#VehicleNo").val("MP2")` then no event listeners are getting invoked.

I've even tried these:

```
 $("#VehicleNo").unbind();
 $("#VehicleNo").off('onchange');
 $("#VehicleNo").removeAttr('onkeypress');
```

But after typing and changing vehicle number change event (or some other) listener is still getting invoked.

I also see this code in the page:

```
document.getElementById('ccMain_RequiredFieldValidator7')['controltovalidate'] = "VehicleNo"
document.getElementById('ccMain_RequiredFieldValidator7')['errormessage'] = "Please Enter Vehicle Number"
document.getElementById('ccMain_RequiredFieldValidator7')['display'] = "Dynamic"
document.getElementById('ccMain_RequiredFieldValidator7')['validationGroup'] = "Register"
document.getElementById('ccMain_RequiredFieldValidator7')['evaluationfunction'] = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid"
document.getElementById('ccMain_RequiredFieldValidator7')['initialvalue'] = ""
document.getElementById('ccMain_RegularExpressionValidator4')['controltovalidate'] = "VehicleNo"
```

What should I do?

Comment: `$("#VehicleNo")[0].onchange = null`

Comment: Mt question: are you removing this attribute after DOM is loaded?

Comment: @Beri Yes after page is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Because your onChange is an attribute, not event added by JavaScript/JQuery then you need to remove it with [removeAttr(attributeName)](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

```
$('#VehicleNo').removeAttr('onchange');
```